# Material UI Modal being dimmed by backdrop

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

I have a modal that is supposed to pop up to show the status of a transaction going through on my website. It works fine other than the fact that the backdrop dimming effect is also applied on top of the modal. My modal is supposed to be white but it ends up being a sort of dark gray. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. [image: Here's how it looks]

Here is the stying for the modal

```
const modalStyle = {
    position: 'absolute' as 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: "80%",
    marginLeft: "auto",
    marginRight: "auto",
    marginTop: "150px",
    marginBottom: "150px",
    bgcolor: 'white',
    boxShadow: 24,
    p: 3,
    borderRadius: "25px"
}
```

And here is the HTML for it:

```
<Modal
    open={open}
    aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
    aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
    sx={modalStyle}
>
    {!done ? (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", height: "100%", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <h1 style={{ fontSize: "50px", textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "700" }}>Transaction Loading...</h1>
            <Box style={{ display: 'flex', width: "300px", height: "300px", justifyContent: "center", }}>
                <CircularProgress style={{ marginTop: "50px" }} size={150} />
            </Box>
        </div>) : (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", height: "100%", alignItems: "center", zIndex: "25" }}>
            <h1 style={{ fontSize: "50px", textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "700" }}>Transaction Completed!</h1>

            <svg className={styles.animatedCheck} viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M4.1 12.7L9 17.6 20.3 6.3" fill="none" />
            </svg>
        </div>)}
</Modal>
```

I don't really know what is going wrong. It's weird because I use a very similar modal declaration at another point in my project and it works completely as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Modal](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-modal/) component simply renders whatever `children` you pass to it in front of a backdrop component -- it's up to you to style the `children`. This issue is happening because, in your code, you're attempting to style the Modal root, not its `children`.

To fix it, wrap your content in another element onto which you can apply your styles and then move your `modalStyle` styling to that element. For my example, I wrapped them in a `Box`:

```
<Modal
  open={open}
  aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
  aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
>
  <Box sx={modalStyle}> {/* Moved here */}
    ...
  </Box>
</Modal>
```

Which produced:
[image: Working screenshot]

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-christian-de6m9k?file=/demo.tsx